# Trouble with display property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am setting the display of a div tag as none in the style property and later i am setting it to display based on-click function. The problem is that when i click on the on-click function it displays it for one second and later it again turns off. Please go through and tell where i am going wrong.

```
   <?php error_reporting(0); 
 $val1=0;
 $irate=0;
 $node=0;

 ?>
<html>
<head>

<link href="style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#inputdiv
{
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px 7px #d1dcf7;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px 7px #d1dcf7;
}
#master
{
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px 7px #d1dcf7;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px 7px #d1dcf7;
}
#node
{
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px 7px #d1dcf7;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px 7px #d1dcf7;
}
html
{
overflow:hidden;
}

body
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
background:url(images/bg.png);
}

#logo
{
width:100%;
height:20%;
border:0px solid black;
}



</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/white.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;position:relative; left:35em"/>
</div>
<hr style="width:100%; height:1px"></hr>
<form action="byte.php" method="post">
<div id="inputdiv" style="position:absolute; left:29em;top:10em">
<select>
<option value="1">Daily</option>
<option value="2">Yearly</option>
</select>
<table>
<tr><td>Total data</td><td><input type="text" name="tdata"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Growth rate</td><td><input type="text" name="growth"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Duration</td><td><select name="duration">
                            <option  value="1">1 year</option>
                            <option  value="2">2 years</option>
                            <option  value="3">3 years</option>
                            <option  value="4">4 years</option>
                            <option  value="5">5 years</option>
                        </select>
                                   </td></tr>
<tr><td>Ingestion data</td><td><?php $total=$_POST['tdata'];
                                     $growth=$_POST['growth'];
                                     $duration=$_POST['duration'];
                                     $irate=($total)+($growth*$duration);
                                     echo $irate;
                                     ?>
                                                      </td></tr>
<tr><td>Raw consumption:</td><td><?php echo $irate*3; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Node raw storage:</td><td>24TB</td></tr>
<tr><td>MapReduce temporary space reserve</td><td>25%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Node-usable raw storage</td><td>18TB</td></tr>
<tr><td>1year(flat growth)</td><td><?php $val1=$_POST['irate'];$node=(round(($irate*3)/24)); echo (round(($irate*3)/24))." nodes";?></td></tr>
</table>
    <div id="master" style="width:300px;position:absolute; left:15em;top:25em;display:none">
   <table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr><td>CPU</td><td width="100%"> 2*6 Core 2.9 Ghz/15 MB cache</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Memory</td><td width="100%"> 64GB DDR3-1600 ECC</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Disk Controller</td><td width="100%"> SAS 6Gb/s</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Disks</td><td width="100%"> 12*2/3 TB LFF SATA II 7200 RPM</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Network Controller</td><td> 2*1Gb Ethernet</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="node" style="width:300px;position:absolute; left:35em;top:25em;display:none">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr><td>CPU</td><td width="100%"> 2*6 Core 2.9 Ghz/15 MB cache</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Memory</td><td width="100%"> 64GB DDR3-1600 ECC</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Disk Controller</td><td width="100%"> SAS 6Gb/s</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Disks</td><td width="100%"> 12*2/3 TB LFF SATA II 7200 RPM</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Network Controller</td><td> 2*1Gb Ethernet</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<input type="submit" onclick="hideshow()" value="submit">
</div>

</form>
<br>

</body>
<script>
function check(){
var node=<?php echo $node; ?>;
console.log(node);
//document.getElementbyId("master").style.display="";
setTimeout(check,1000);


}
check();

 function hideshow()
 {
 //if(document.getElementById("master").style.display='none')
 //{
  //$('#master').show();
//}
$("#master").css("display", "block");
  var node=<?php echo $node; ?>;
  if(node >20)
  {
  $('#node').show();
  }

 }


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a click function

Comment: Where is the onClick event handler? Where is hideshow() invoked?

Comment: Where are you firing click event

Comment: where is the node id?

Comment: See that div tag is kept inside a form tag and the click event is fired on-click of submit button.

Comment: guys i have just provided a code-snippet so please work with that.

Comment: Have you tried using visibility in your css not display. If you are trying to do what i think it would work better.

Comment: @jibindcruz debug that are you able to go inside the if condition by write the alert before the show function.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, my hunch is screaming at me.

**1st point:**

I'm presuming that you have an onclick handler somewhere that calls `hideshow()` directly? Even if it doesn't, it doesn't matter, the point is you've put it on a `submit` button.

My guess is that you're clicking the submit button, your div appears, then the page refreshes and it appears that your element has disappeared again.

Inside your event function, let's assume it is `hideshow()` for now, pass the event info through as a parameter, and `preventDefault`. This will stop the `submit` button from performing its default behaviour (submitting your form).

```
function hideshow(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    ///other stuff

}
```

**2nd point:**

If you have a function called "hideshow()", that is, it *hides and shows* an element (also looking at your commented code as more evidence for this), I'm presuming you'll want to use jQuery `toggle()`. `toggle` will hide something that is visible (`display:none`), or show something that is invisible (`display:block`).

so, change:

```
$("#master").css("display", "block");
```

to:

```
$("#master").toggle();
```

jQuery Toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

**3rd point:**

I did a lot of hunch digging, soul searching and detective work to provide this answer. If this is correct, it was all down to luck and well-made assumptions. I believe there are other things you can do in your question asking to make things a little easier for us in future questions.

Comment: i want submit button to do what its doing na, so why should i prevent it? just check my edit to see the whole code

Comment: @Jace Your first point looks correct, especially now that the OP provided more code

Comment: @jibindcruz I have checked your code. A submit button refreshes the page/navigates to a new page (via the GET/POST request process). So, either you want your element to appear, and stay open, or you want to refresh the page. You can't do both. Unless you POST a variable to the next page and dynamically set whether or not `#master` is visible. But that is outside the scope of this question. You question is about the `display` property, and I believe I have solved that for you.